# How to set and use last bit of an INT64

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to know how to use all bits of an INT64 in Bigquery.

The following works fine:

```sql
DECLARE myBits INT64 DEFAULT 0x0000000000000001;
```

The following example does not work, with the error further below being reported:

```sql
DECLARE myBits INT64 DEFAULT 0x8000000000000000;
```

> Query error: Invalid hex integer literal: 0x8000000000000000

This HEX works perfectly in MS SQL Server, but not within Bigquery.

I tried:

```sql
DECLARE myBits BYTES(16) DEFAULT FROM_HEX('8000000000000000');
```

But when I try to use the above with some bitwise operations (&, |), the results are not what I expect.

From the documentation, it seems that INT64 should be used - how can I assign a value so that I can use **all** bits?

**EDIT** - Solutions

With some more searching and experimenting I found a solution:

```sql
/* This INT64 number only has the 64th bit set to 1 and all others 0. */
DECLARE e INT64 DEFAULT -9223372036854775808;
```

I also just tested the answer provided by Roar S, and got it to work with the following:

```sql
/* 0x1 only has the right most bit set to 1,
 * then we shift this bit 63 positions to the left,
 * resulting in the same as above.
 */
DECLARE a INT64 DEFAULT (0x1 << 63);
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the issue. You should consider answering your own question, it is an interesting topic. BR

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
declare myBits BYTES default B'\x00\xf1'; -- 4 nibbles = 2 bytes = 16 bits
declare mask BYTES default B'\x00\x01'; -- for masking out least significant bit

select TO_HEX((mask & myBits)) -- will return 0001 which is least significant bit (LSB) set
```

Playing with shift left

```
select TO_HEX((B'\x01' << 3))
```

will return `08` because we started with `0000 0001`, moved the 1 three positions to the left and ended up with `0000 1000`.

Please note that `select BIT_COUNT(B'\xff\xff')` will return 16, while `select BIT_COUNT(B'\x00\x00')` will return 0.

[Bytes doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#bytes_type)

[Operators doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators)